# Downloading DeSmuME (Gtk) Error

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, dependencies

I went to install DeSmuME (Gtk) (Nintendo Ds Emulator) and I encountered error message.

```
$ sudo apt-get install desmume

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
desmume: Depends: libasound2 (>= 1.0.16) but 1.0.27.2-3ubuntu7 is to be installed
     Depends: libc6 (>= 2.15) but 2.19-0ubuntu6.6 is to be installed
     Depends: libcairo2 (>= 1.2.4) but 1.13.0~20140204-0ubuntu1.1 is to be installed
     Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1) but 1:4.9.1-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
     Depends: libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 (>= 2.22.0) but 2.30.7-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
     Depends: libglade2-0 (>= 1:2.6.1) but 1:2.6.4-2 is to be installed
     Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.35.9) but 2.40.2-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
     Depends: libgtk2.0-0 (>= 2.24.0) but 2.24.23-0ubuntu1.2 is to be installed
     Depends: libgl1-mesa-glide3 but it is not going to be installed
     Depends: libpango1.0-0 (>= 1.14.0) but 1.36.3-1ubuntu1.1 is to be installed
     Depends: libsdl1.2debian (>= 1.2.11) but 1.2.15-8ubuntu1.1 is to be installed
     Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.4.0) but 4.8.2-19ubuntu1 is to be installed
     Depends: zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4) but 1:1.2.8.dfsg-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
```

Output of `apt-cache policy desmume`

```
Output:
 Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.9.9-1
  Version table:
     0.9.9-1 0
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
```

Comment: What do you want to install exactly?

Comment: Ane add a tag with your Ubuntu version.

Comment: I am trying to download DeSmuME (Gtk) and my version is 14.04

Comment: Please edit your question and add this.

Comment: Edit your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy desmume`

Comment: what should i edit my question to?

Comment: Open a terminal, run the command `apt-cache policy desmume` and copy the output into your question.

Comment: Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.9.9-1
  Version table:
     0.9.9-1 0
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages

Comment: Please place the output IN your question.

Comment: i have move the output into the question

Comment: With what command you have started the installation?

Comment: i didnt i went ot download it from the software store

Comment: when i do it through the terminal i get:  Command: sudo apt-get install DeSmuME
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 desmume : Depends: libosmesa6 (>= 6.5.2-1) but it is not going to be installed or
                    libgl1-mesa-glide3 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: Can you install `aptitude` with this command: `sudo apt-get install aptitude`?

Comment: yes what do i have to do now?

Comment: `sudo aptitude install desmume` It offered solutions. You need to choose a suitable one.

Comment: what do i do now The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)     desmume [Not Installed]                            
2)     libglapi-mesa [Not Installed]                      
3)     libosmesa6 [Not Installed]

Comment: Press `n` and check the next solution.

Comment: I Get 303 things to be removed should i press y or n?

Comment: Check the next solution `n`

Comment: then i get 63 things to be removed what next?

Comment: again, the next `n`

Comment: i keep pressing n and i get open: 475; closed: 2080; defer: 152; conflict:238

Comment: Is there again a `n`?

Comment: i have the option but as i said in my last comment i get this thing telling me something i dont under stand

Comment: We need a chat.

Comment: why do we need a chat?

Comment: to post error messages

Comment: ok are you going to create one

Comment: Hmm, i will try

Comment: ok if you make one can you leave a link to it in this comment

Comment: Start `aptitude`again and post the 63 things to be removed

Comment: Can you join? https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23858/downloading-desmume-gtk-error

Comment: i can join but i need more reputation to chat and i cant start amplitude again because when i start it it goes as if it will start it but it just crashes the terminal

Comment: terminal crash?

Comment: no not crash sorry i mean it just takes me back as if i want to enter another command

Comment: start `sudo aptitude install desmume` again

Comment: Now you have write access in the chat

Answer (score 0):

After we have discussed in the chat, here is the solution:

Install the tool `aptitude`

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
```

Start the installation again with

```
sudo aptitude install desmume
```

It offered a number of possible solutions, choose a suitable proposal.
Accept a solution with <kbd>Y</kbd> or see another one with <kbd>N</kbd>